# SQL query for post and replies

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
post Table
 post_id
 post_name
 post_summary
 date

post_reply Table
 parent_id
 post_id
```

So what I am doing is I inset a new post detail in post table and if  there is any reply for that post then I put all the detail in post table itself and also stores the main post id as parent_id and replyed post id as post_id in post_reply.

Now I want to fetch all the posts and their reply under the main post if there is any and want to display the same on my jsp page.

I can't write a single query to fetch these details. I can do it by first fetching all the post whose ids are not in post_reply and then loop on all post and then fetch the main post and replied post one by one.

I just want to fetch all these in one query. Is this possible? I am using mysql as database and using spring mvc with mybatis. So I am fecthing the whole list and putting it in my model attribute and display it on jsp page.

If someone can suggested me a better way of achieving this like changing my database structure or any other solution then that would be great.

Comment: Have you tried to do anything yet?  Look at using JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

table post

```
+---------+-------+---------+
| post_id | post  | comment |
+---------+-------+---------+
|       1 | kjasd | ajsdh   |
|       2 | abc   | dfgdfg  |
|       3 | ashdf | NULL    |
+---------+-------+---------+
```

table post_reply

```
+-----------+---------+
| parent_id | post_id |
+-----------+---------+
|         1 |       2 |
+-----------+---------+
```

Use this query it is working:

```
select *from post where post_id=1 or post_id in (select post_id from post_reply where parent_id=1);
```

It will return the reply with parent post and parent post only if there is no reply..

Comment: Hi Astrowalker thanks, This seems to be a good query but how I can replace hard coded post_id at runtime?

Comment: try this but you cannot get specific detail of a post without post id...      select *from post where post_id in (select post_id from post_reply where parent_id=post_id);

Comment: select *from post where post_id in (select post_id from post_reply,post where post_reply.parent_id=post.post_id)

Comment: it only shows reply posts , does not show main posts and does not show posts which does not have any reply.

Comment: without giving the post id the thing expected by u is not possible u need to give one value to the query that is only efficient method otherwise data handling is more and not possible

Comment: you mean I need to loop into post table and use its post_id in your query?

Answer (score 0):

You want to join the two tables together.

For example,

```
SELECT     *
FROM       post
INNER JOIN post_reply 
ON         post.post_id = post_reply.post_id
```

I'm not sure from your question exactly what you are after, but if this doesn't do what you want, you might want to use GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly simple Join query that do this I would think. Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM post pt JOIN (post_reply pr) ON pr.parent_id = pt.post_id
```

You would then loop through the results in PHP like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($your_query)) {
  $parent_id = $row['post_id'];
  $reply_id = $row['post_id'];
  $content = $row['post_summary'];
}
```

You could then build your reply table from the details above

Answer (score 0):

Query a list of CITY names from STATION for cities that have an even ID number. Print the results in any order, but exclude duplicates from the answer.
The STATION table is described as follows:

Station.jpg

Answer

select distinct city from station where mod(id,2) = 0;

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Your station.jpg image didn't get included in your answer.  Also, when you want to include code, wrap it in back-ticks, so it `looks like this`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your station.jpg image didn't get included in your answer. Also, when you want to include code, wrap it in back-ticks, so it `looks like this`